# Show outline or table of content using presets in Scrivener?

Tags: formatting, software, scrivener, outline

Google Docs has this neat feature, where an outline is generated based on the text you've set to a specific style, such as title or heading:

[image: screenshot of outline with different styles]

Word has a similar feature. Is there a way to generate an outline like this in Scrivener using presets as you're typing?

Answer (score 4):

### This answer is current as of Scrivener 3

You have a couple of options/features to view your outline:

#### 1. Outline View

While selecting a folder or a text file in the binder, go to `view` → `outline`. On MacOS this is simply achieved by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>. Here is a snapshot I created using a template:

[image]

#### 2. Table Of Content

If what you are looking for is more like a table of content, then you can create a TOC as follows:

1. Add a new text file and rename it `TOC`, for instance.
2. Select a folder in your binder, select `view` → `Outline` → `Expand all`, or on MacOS <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>.
3. In the binder, select all the items you want in your TOC, as so:

[image]

4. Select: `Edit` → `Copy` → `Copy Documents as ToC`.
5. Go to the empty text you created in step 1, then paste. You'll receive a ToC settings dialog, change settings to your liking then you should see something like this:

[image]

**Note:** The TOC copy you created is only updated when page numbers change. It is not updated with folder/text renames, or order changes.

Comment: Great in depth answer - +1

Comment: Good answer I guess (very detailed), but it's not really what I'm looking for and it misses the point of the question: I wanted to create a TOC of the content *within* the file I'm currently in. I want to have an easy way to jump between different parts of the same file.

Comment: Too bad that didn't help. My apologies for misunderstanding your question. But you didn't mention that you needed to navigate inside a single document. You may consider highlighting the beginnings of parts, then use the _Formatting Finder_. This isn't exactly seamless but I think it involves the least effort for what you want.

Comment: I wanted to add that this feature exists in [Ulysess](https://ulysses.app/).